# Push the current branch to a different repo on PR approval

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I need a workflow to keep a third-party repo up to date after a PR passes an internal review process.

This is how the process looks:
`third party repo` -> `pull/branch to local` -> `push to owned repo` -> `owned repo pr` -> `pr approval` -> `push to third party repo`

I need a workflow that can automate the last step when the approval is made. Essentially, it should push the current branch to a target repo when a PR on the current repo is approved.

Answer (score -1):

This action is working:

```
name: Push Branch on PR Approval

on:
  pull_request_review:
    types: [submitted]
        
permissions:
  contents: write

jobs:
  push_branch:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}  
        fetch-depth: 0
        repository: <OWNER>/<OWNED REPO NAME>
        token: <OWNED REPO TOKEN>
          
    - name: Check if approval status is changes_requested
      id: check_approval
      run: |
            if [ $(git branch --show-current) == 'development' ]; then
              exit 130 # CTRL-C the script
            fi
            APPROVAL_STATUS=$(jq -r ".review.state" "$GITHUB_EVENT_PATH")
            if [ "$APPROVAL_STATUS" != "approved" ]; then
              echo "::set-output name=approved::false"
            else
              echo "::set-output name=approved::true"
            fi
        
    - name: Push branch to different repository
      if: ${{ (steps.check_approval.outputs.approved == 'true') && (github.ref != 'refs/heads/development') }}
      run: |
            TARGET_REPO="<TARGET OWNER>/<TARGET REPO NAME>" # Replace with the target repository in the format owner/target-repo
            git remote add destination https://<TARGET REPO URL KEY>@github.com/$TARGET_REPO.git
            git push --no-thin --set-upstream destination $(git branch --show-current)
```

Replace these values: OWNER, OWNED REPO NAME, OWNED REPO TOKEN, TARGET OWNER, TARGET REPO NAME, TARGET REPO URL KEY (remove carats).

Put it in a yml file in the workflows folder and it should work.

Comment: I don't think `git branch --show-current` works as the value of a branch, does it?

Comment: I think you're right. After a few iterations, we went with something else. Now we do: `ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}  fetch-depth: 0`

Comment: Pretty sure that's the default behaviour and can just be skipped.